# grow a tooth, fall a tooth, and loose a tooth

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, vocabulary

I've got a tooth grown.
I've got a tooth loosened.
I've got a tooth fallen.
Are the sentences above correct?
If no, how should I say them instead?
I'll be grateful to them, if anybody answers my question.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to say with these sentences. Can you please describe a situation when you might use each sentence, then we can suggest an appropriate alternative?

Comment: Suppose I had 28 teeth. But now I have 27. So can I say that 'I have a tooth fallen? If one of my teeth moves, can I say 'I have a tooth loosened'?  Am I clear to you now?

Comment: You would say, "I lost a tooth." Or, "One of my teeth fell out."  "I have a loose tooth."

Answer (score 6):

I am Canadian, so we might say it differently than say the UK. I think that none of your examples work.

- My tooth has come in. / My tooth finally erupted*.  * less common.
- I have a loose tooth. (A child might say a wiggly tooth.)
- My tooth fell out. / I lost a tooth.

I can [LINK](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/tc/wisdom-tooth-problems-topic-overview#1)  but all the link does is show you the language in use. I can't find a good dictionary definition.

Comment: That works for the US, too.

Comment: These would all be used in the US, too, for babies and young children. It would be pretty rare for the first situation to be in the first person, though, just because we only usually talk about baby teeth coming in, and babies aren't usually that articulate. I would add *(the baby/I) **cut a tooth*** for the first situation, in AmE. Also, if an adult tooth is *knocked* loose, it might be possible to say *I have a **loosened** tooth*.

Comment: @1006a -- I automatically thought of a wisdom tooth because the OP is adult enough to not be having baby teeth. Wisdom teeth come in in young adulthood -- seventeen years of age -- or so. Good point re 'cutting' a tooth.

Comment: @Willow Wisdom teeth might not erupt until later though.  In my early thirties, I had a wisdom tooth removed (there was enough room for it, and it had been for a number of years, but it broke crunching on an uncooked grain of rice). The x-ray at the time revealed that I had at least one other un-erupted wisdom tooth (that could, in principal, reveal itself someday).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor  that is exceptional and this is about the English, not our dental experiences.. However, I had 5 wisdom teeth and one erupted in my 30s... ;)

Answer (score 0):

None of those adjectives (words modifying the noun tooth) are quite correct. I would suggest new, loose, and missing.

A more important lesson to learn here is that you are putting these words in the wrong place. In English the adjective usually goes before the noun it modifies.

- I've got a new tooth.
- I've got a loose tooth.
- I've got a missing tooth.
- I lost a tooth. (no adjective in this one)

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a tooth grown.

This sounds like you have a garden where you are growing teeth as plants or like bacteria in a petri dish.  You want to say this:

> I've got a tooth grown *in*.

---

> I've got a tooth loosened

This sounds like you asked to have someone loosen your tooth.  But in regards to a child having their first teeth fall out, the teeth "loosen themselves."  You want to say this:

> I've got a loose tooth OR I've got a tooth loose.

---

> I've got a tooth fallen

*Fallen* when used like this is synonymous with *defeated in battle* - which doesn't work with teeth unless you are fighting them, and really doesn't work with *got* unless you are a battle medic, etc.  You want to say this:

> I've got a tooth that fell out OR My tooth fell out